# Pycharm: Wrong root directory when creating a new project

Tags: pycharm

I have two projects in my computer and I am trying to create a new one lets call it pj3, and lets call the two projects I have pj1 and ph2.

Well the problem is that when I create the new project pj3, its root directory is set to pj2 (if I check the .idea directory, there is no .iml file and if I grep the word pj2 it appears several times in the xml files.)

If I try to change the root directory it seems to work, however the name of the folder that pycharm shows in the left sidebar (in projects) has a strange name: pj3 **[pj2]**. And even more strange (if possible) if i close the project and open pj2 the root directory is set to pj3.

I tried everything and I do not know what is going on, that never happened to me before.

By the way I am running pycharm 2017.1 on osx

Comment: I moved back to pycharm 2016.1 and I dont have the problem anymore.